# Best way to refactor complex if expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement, expression

I have just come on board to a big e-commerce project that has an angularJS front-end. I have been tasked with adding a lot of complex features to the checkout pages... which already have a lot of complex logic.

To make things harder I keep coming across lots of `if` statement expressions like the one below which are making it hard to understand and it is a slow process going through this code with many of these type of `if` expressions.

Some of these expressions are pretty critical and are sometimes even longer... There are no unit tests and when I ask other devs what this is checking for and why (just to be sure I understand) I usually get pointed to someone else rather than an explanation.

```
if ((!previousBillingAddress) || (previousBillingAddress && previousBillingAddress.id !== bag.paymentAddress.id)){
    console.log('all of the above was true'); // just a dummy log
} else {
    console.log('all of the above was false'); // just a dummy log
}
```

Does anyone have a good tip for refactoring these types of expressions?

I thought of breaking them down into functions that have descriptive names and the functions could return `true` or `false` but Im not sure if there is a better way.

Comment: `previousBillingAddress` this part of the expression is redundant. After you  remove it it would be easier to manage.

Comment: Maybe someone more experienced will have better input, but my initial thought was like you said, to build boolean helper functions with names that describe what expression they are testing.

Comment: `I thought of breaking them down into functions that have descriptive names [...]`
That's a great idea in my opinion.

Comment: It's saying "if `previousBillingAddress` is falsy or previousBillingAddress is not falsy and it's `id` is equal to the `bag.paymentAddress.id`." In this case you could change it to "if `previousBillingAddress` is falsy or the IDs are equal." No point if checking if it's both falsy and truthy. In general, creating descriptive variables for each expression is a good idea. When you create descriptive variables it also allows you to get a better look at the whole of the expression. Then you can determine what parts can be removed or changed.

Answer (score 2):

Let there be

```
A = previousBillingAddress 
B = previousBillingAddress.id !== bag.paymentAddress.id
```

then your expression is:

```
if (!A || (A && B)) {
  log1
} else {
  log2
}
```

What we can do we with `!A || (A && B)`? It's equal to `!A || B`:

```
A   |  B  |  !A  |  A && B  |  !A || (A && B)  |  !A || B
==========================================================
1   |  1  |   0  |    1     |        1         |     1
1   |  0  |   0  |    0     |        0         |     0
0   |  1  |   1  |    0     |        1         |     1
0   |  0  |   1  |    0     |        1         |     1
```

That's why your expression is equal to:

```
if (!previousBillingAddress || previousBillingAddress.id !== bag.paymentAddress.id) {
    console.log('all of the above was true'); // just a dummy log
} else {
    console.log('all of the above was false'); // just a dummy log
}
```

**TL;DR**

Above table is only check if `!A || (A && B)` is equal to `!A || B`. How to guess `!A || B`? In case of such expressions it's good to play with following rules:

```
A == !(!(A))                        (rule 1)
!(A && B) == !A || !B               (rule 2)
!(A || B) == !A && !B               (rule 3)
A && (B || C) == A && B || A && C   (rule 4)
```

So we have `!A || (A && B)`, let's play. Due to rule 1 it's equal to

```
!(!(!A || (A && B)))
```

Now we use rule 3:

```
!(!(!A || (A && B))) == !(A && !( A && B))
```

Rule 2:

```
!(A && !( A && B)) == !(A && (!A || !B))           (*)
```

Due to rule 4:

```
A && (!A || !B) == (A && !A) || (A && !B)
```

We have `(A && !A) || (A && !B)` and it can be reduce to `(A && !B)`. Now we can back to `(*)` and we have:

```
!(A && (!A || !B)) == !((A && !A) || (A && !B)) == !(A && !B)
```

With rule 2 we got:

```
!(A && !B) == !A || B
```

Answer (score 1):

You can drop the `previousBillingAddress &&` part - in the second operand of the `||` you already have estblished that `previousBillingAddress` is not falsy. That would make the overall condition

```
if (!previousBillingAddress || previousBillingAddress.id !== bag.paymentAddress.id) {
    console.log('all of the above was true'); // just a dummy log
} else {
    console.log('all of the above was false'); // just a dummy log
}
```

which seems short enough for me. If not, make an appropriately named helper function to which you pass the `previousBillingAddress` and the `bag`.

Answer (score 0):

Comments are our best friend. You want to make sure that the next person to take a look at your code knows **exactly what it is supposed to do** and from that, it will be quicker and easier to see **exactly what it is doing**.

In this case the expression in the if statement can be shortened. This is how I would comment it with almost a pseudocode approach:

```
// we need to check if the user has, and is using, a previous billing address
if (previousBillingAddress && previousBillingAddress.id === bag.paymentAddress.id)){

    // the user is using a previous billing address

    // do some work with the previous billing address

} else {

    // the user is using a new address

    // do some work with the new address

    // save the new billing address

}
```

**Note that `previousBillingAddress` is the main subject of this if statement.** If we are checking for previousBillingAddress then in our first block we want to make sure we deal with what happens if we have a previous billing address. It's more logical that way.

It makes a lot less sense to check if we don't have a previous billing address and then what do we do if we have one.

Look how clean and logical it is! <3

Answer (score 0):

In my personal opinion, i think you can refactor and encapsulate the validation/check inside of a function, then if the same validation applies to other part of your code (file/module/etc..), you can reuse it. In this case you are using angular, so might be good to use an angular custom service for this type of business validations, since they also can manipulate the scope

Answer (score 0):

I recommend hoisting the complex conditionals into Boolean variables (or constants, if your supported level of JS allows you to use `const`). For example:

```
var weakPrevBillingAddress = 
      !previousBillingAddress || 
      (previousBillingAddress && 
        (previousBillingAddress.id !== bag.paymentAddress.id));

if (weakPrevBillingAddress) {
  console.log('judged weak previousBillingAddress');
  // other processing expected here
} else {
  console.log('judged strong previousBillingAddress');
  // other processing expected here
}
```

As you and [philip yoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4803039/philip-yoo) suggest, you could hoist the conditional into a Boolean helper function. But most of the ways of defining such functions will put the logic farther away from the point of use, making comprehension harder. Boolean variables (a.k.a. "predicates") can be easily defined close to their use (e.g. right before your `if` statement). So there isn't much additional distance, but they still separate the computation of the Boolean value from its use. Your ability to focus on the computation separately can make things simpler and more comprehensible. As shown above, it also allows you to split long
lines and use indentation for better clarity.

I don't know if you have the flexibility to rename existing variable names. If you do, the ones you're using are exceedingly long. Long names can help increase understanding, but a 22-character name repeated several times per line is distracting, not clarifying. Shorter names, either for the source values, or just for the predicates you compute, can help. E.g.:

```
var weakPrevBA = !prevBA || 
      (prevBA.id !== bag.paymentAddress.id);
```

Choosing good variable names is an art, and developer tastes about "how much description is enough" vary. But in an app that deals with billing addresses all the time, line after line after line, spelling out `billingAddress` every time doesn't necessarily help. If you're reading the code and comments, you probably are highly aware you're dealing with billing addresses. If not, add a quick comment, rather than spell out the full concept multiple times per line.

Note that I've also simplified the Boolean expression in this shorter example. (This was also [suggested by Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39358355/240490.)) That can be a good idea--as long you're sure it can be simplified correctly. However, do this only with great caution. You don't have unit tests, so you have no easy way to test if simplifications are truly identical. And you're dealing with complex code. I recommend keeping the original Boolean expressions, at least to start (possibly with shortened names). That reduces one place bugs can creep in, at least until you understand the code more fully. The better you understand the code, and the simpler you have made it (e.g. by adding computed predicates, rather than long, complex expressions inside conditionals), the more freedom and safety you have in rewriting expressions.

Comment: @user1806692 Please consider up-voting answers that were helpful to you, and/or marking one of them as "the preferred answer" (by clicking the checkmark at the top left of the answer).

Answer (score -1):

Something like this

```
var billingId = previousBillingAddress && previousBillingAddress.id;

if (billingId || billingId === bag.paymentAddress.id){
    console.log('all of the above was false'); // just a dummy log
} else {
    console.log('all of the above was true'); // just a dummy log
}
```

what i did

1. since you are using `if` and `else` its not a good practice to use negation in the if statement. so i removed that

if you only want the negated part (without an else)

```
if (!(billingId || billingId === bag.paymentAddress.id)){
    console.log('all of the above was true'); // just a dummy log
}
```

2. the && will return the first false, or the last true value. so `billingId` will equal `false` or the `id`. building upon that, your first if is checking if its `"falsey"` continue, so you can use the same variable as well.